# blockUI not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-blockui

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#viewSOA').click(function(){
            $.blockUI({message:'<h3>Loading,Please wait...</h3>'});
            location.reload();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am using this script to show blockUI. When I test in Firefox or Chrome, it works. But it doesn't effect when I click viewSOA link in Internet Explorer.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You are reloading the page... probably IE flushes the page before your message is displayed ? You cannot control this behavior i'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

just avoid `location.reload();`

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#viewSOA').click(function(){
            $.blockUI({message:'<h3>Loading,Please wait...</h3>'});
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is worked for me.